# SSIS error: Connection manager has not been assigned to the Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, connection, mdac

I have an issue trying to import data from Excel file (Source.xlsx) using dtsx package.

The system is Windows Server 2019 Standard and there is no MS Office installation on this server, so I installed MDAC 2010 32 bit and added Excel Connection Manager in the Connection Manager
[Excel Connection Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xB3yy.jpg)

After that I added Excel Source in the Data Flow Task, but I couldn't choose name of the Excel sheet with the error:

```
Data Flow Task: Data Flow Task: A connection manager has not been assigned to the Excel Source.Connections[OleDbConnection]
```

It's the first time when using MDAC doesn't help in such case. I was looking for any solution and I can assume that only solution is to install MDAC 2010 32bit, but unfortunately it does't help in my case.

It would be so kind to get any suggestions and tips to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Finally I've found a workaround solution - set the name of the Excel sheet (for example "Sheet1$") right in the property "OpenRowset" of the Excel Source Task. It seems that I've faced with a kind of bug. However I'm still looking for proper way to find the root of this issue.

Comment: Did you change the package to run in 32-bit mode as well?

Comment: Yes, sure, I tried switch run mode from 64-bit to 32-bit but the result was the same.